# what framework to use for python card game?

Tags: python, pyqt, pygame

my question is quite simple, but I can't move on until I solve it. I want to develop a card game, something like Magic the Gathering. I suppose there will be just a little of animation, but much work with images, image transformation and special rendering - some kind of things, that every unit has now attack plus 2 so cards on table will adapt.

I thought Python will be best for it, because it easy to develop with it and I know it pretty well. Also I have a little of experience with PyQt and Pygame. But I can't decide which one is better for that purpose. What do you think will be easier to use: PyQt, Pygame or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want just a simple animation and want to finish your game fast. use the pyqt's scene view. refer to (Rapid GUI programming using python and pyqt) book if you want to learn more about scene view.

Answer (score 1):

[PySolitaire](http://pygames.sourceforge.net) is a collection of more than 300 solitaire and Mahjongg games. So maybe if you browse around, perhaps you can get some idea.

What is better? If you are developing games, PyGame I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Both pygame and pyqt will work for what you want to do, but I'd recommend pyqt: you'll be able to use standard widgets (like listboxes, textboxes, menus, buttons, ...).
I've never worked with pyqt myself, but I image that drag 'n drop is something built-in, which will be really useful for a card game.

With pygame on the other hand you'll have to make everything yourself. This will give it more of a game feel as you can draw everything exactly like you want it to look like, but it'll take more work as you have to implement basic stuff yourself.